# artifact upload failes from docker contianer and works from docker node

Tags: docker, jenkins, continuous-integration

I am trying to upload artifact from jenkins pipleine which upload artifact to jfrog and it works fine from docker Node but fails from docker continer.

using same username and password in both senarios

error:
Oct 07, 2023 3:53:11 PM org.jfrog.hudson.util.JenkinsBuildInfoLog warn
WARNING: Error occurred for request PUT /artifactory/project/package.2.9.0.157.zip;build.timestamp=1696689635416;build.name=project+%3A%3A+trprojectname+%3A%3A+develop;vcs.revision=2f0cdfd36e1e5193b2b91873113ea46aa790b7fa;build.number=157;vcs.url=https%3A%2F%2Fpdidev.visualstudio.com%2FDefaultCollection%2FTransPac%2F_git%2projects HTTP/1.1: Connection reset by peer: socket write error.
Oct 07, 2023 3:53:11 PM org.jfrog.hudson.util.JenkinsBuildInfoLog error
SEVERE: [consumer_0] An exception occurred during execution:
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.clientConfiguration.util.spec.SpecDeploymentConsumer.consumerRun(SpecDeploymentConsumer.java:44)
at org.jfrog.build.extractor.producerConsumer.ConsumerRunnableBase.run(ConsumerRunnableBase.java:11)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error

- validated user and password
- same commands or job works from docker Node
- able to upload from continer when tried manulaly with out issue